# Self hosted agent publish failing with access is denied error while running pipeline for Web API project

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to publish Web API project using Azure DevOps pipeline with Self hosted agent. It is building properly but failing in publish step with following error:

```
##[error]One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Access to the path 'f:\agent\_work\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.181.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll' is denied.)) (Access to the path 'f:\agent\_work\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.181.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll' is denied.)
```

Strangely, when I remove class project references (Infra & application layer) from Web API project then publish is working fine.

I even tried removing *_work* folder but no use.

We are using on-premises version of AzureDevOps

Expecting publish to complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Facing a similar issue. My pipeline had some Dotnet CLI and SonarQube tasks, but even after removing those, we still see an issue.

[One workaround](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/azure-devops-build-initialize-job-itself-is-failing-with-error-access-denied-error/85106/3) is to use dotnet build with argument nodeReuse:false. Not sure if it's a fluke that builds have started succeeding.

If you have any Sonar steps, those might be the cause of the issue.